# Getting timezone from zipcode/postal code in postgreSQL

Tags: python, node.js, database, postgresql, heroku

I am finding a solution related to timezone in my application.
Currently I am using Heroku and postgreSQL. Is there a way in postgreSQL by using which I can get the 'Timezone" from "Zipcode/Postal code" with out using a separate table for Country/places with timezone. I want to use any function or API. If this can be resolved by using Python/Node.js also please guide me.

Comment: Please provide some example code that you've already tried or some input and expected output. For working with timezones in python I reccomend [pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/).

Answer (score 0):

Write it yourself.

You can identify the state (almost always) by the first two numbers of the zipcode. The very few gaps shouldn't cross over time zone boundaries.

This means you only have 100 entries to store.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_code#By_geography